# Enable Angular Component to show multiple table rows without breaking table formatting

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have an Angular component that shows one or more table rows in a standard html table, like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
     <td>Person</td>
     <td>Monday</td>
     <td>Tuesday</td>
     <td>Wednesday</td>
     <td>Thursday</td>
     <td>Friday</td>
     <td>Total</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <person-row *ngFor="let person of people" ></person-row> 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And then in `person-row.component.html`:

```
<tr>
  <td>{{person.name}}</td>
  <td ngFor="let day of person.available">
     {{day}}
  </td>
  <td>{{sumDays(person.available)}}</td>
</tr>
<tr *ngIf="editMode">
  <td> Edit: </td>
  <td ngFor="let day of person.available">
     <!-- availability toggle checkbox -->
  </td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

In the parent component scss I direct the browser to ignore the person-row:

```
person-row {
   display: table-row-group;
}
```

This all nearly works, but the resulting table still puts the whole `person-row` content into the first column of the table.

| Person | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice yes yes no yes no 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Bob no yes no no yes 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| edit [] [x] [] [] [x] [save] |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Claire no no yes yes yes 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |

*Note that this is a significant simplification over my existing code to demonstrate the problem, I am aware that in this case the edit row could simply be swapped in place!*

Is it possible to show multiple rows using an angular component and have it fit into the existing table formatting, and if so how?

Comment: I would think you could just change your component selector to a property, rather than a tag, like `[appPersonRow]` and then apply the selector to the `tbody`. Then you won't have the extra, non-table-compliant markup in the table

Comment: @BrandonTaylor I hadn't thought of this but it makes sense as long as I don't mind having lots of tbody elements in my table, which is fine and seems acceptable in HTML. Do you want to phrase this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a property selector and attach the `*ngFor` to the `tbody` element.

```js
@Component({
  selector: '[appPersonRow]',
  template: `
    <tr>
      <td>{{person.name}}</td>
      <td ngFor="let day of person.available">
        {{day}}
    </td>
    <td>{{sumDays(person.available)}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngIf="editMode">
    <td> Edit: </td>
    <td ngFor="let day of person.available">
      <!-- availability toggle checkbox -->
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  `
})
export class PersonRowComponent {}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
     <td>Person</td>
     <td>Monday</td>
     <td>Tuesday</td>
     <td>Wednesday</td>
     <td>Thursday</td>
     <td>Friday</td>
     <td>Total</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody [appPersonRow] *ngFor="let person of people">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You'll end up with multiple `tbody` elements, but I can't see another way to iterate over two `tr` elements at a time, as you can't bind a property selector to `ng-container`.

If you don't want to have a separate component, you can use `*ngFor` on an `ng-container` and the HTML will be cleaner, but obviously you'll have a larger component.

Answer (score 2):

maybe there is no need for such a small component, maybe it's more convenient to have a person component representing the whole table, because the html elements of thetable are too interconnected

despite that...except using directive, you can set `display: contents;` to your table row component, but it is not supported in some browsers and there may be other consequences of "hiding" the host element

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in my real code there definitely is a need for the component and because I may have a lot of rows I do need them to all be in the same table or I risk things getting broken up in weird ways. `display: table-row-group` is like a more refined `display: contents` specifically for this kind of case, but apparently not one that works very well!